# LEFT JOIN on AFTER INSERT Trigger in MariaDB or MySQL?

Tags: mysql, join, mariadb, trigger, insert

Is there any simple way to access records related to a new one that is causing a trigger?

I am allocating expenses for vehicle use, by creating a general journal entry via AFTER INSERT Trigger when a new vehicle use record is created.

Problem is, I need a lot of info that is related to the new vehicle use record.

Currently, I am doing a number of sub-selects that I'm sure would be more efficient as a LEFT JOIN. For example, NEW.Driver is the ID of a User, the cost per kilometre is in a Vehicle_cost table keyed by NEW.Vehicle, and I also need the Name of the NEW.Vehicle, and the general journal Source and Destination accounts are referenced (in part) by NEW.Project.

I can post my ugly code, but I was hoping the view from 40,000 feet might inspire some better strategy than using a bunch of sub-selects.

Thanks!

Comment: Can we see the code?

Comment: Assume each `NEW.field` as a literal value, not whole `NEW` as a table. And I think a lot of separate SELECT (which stores found values from another tables into local variables for future use or inserts them into some table immediately) will be more fast then one complex query.

Comment: To give more detailed recommendations you must publish your trigger code and DDLs for all tables relative to your question at least. And specify your server version.